# Conditionally take value

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query returns value as below

```
ID      Hvalue
0       34
SGL210      91
```

if the resultset ID has 0 and non zero value I need to retrive
Only non zero Hvalue.If the resultset has only ID value as 0 Then 
I have retrive that Hvalue can somebody help me in this.

Comment: make your question more clear ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take the first value from the query - after sorting it by the ID in descending order:-

```
select top 1 hvalue
from ...
... your query
...
order by ID desc
```

A more robust approach (following comment by Vikdor) would be:-

```
select top 1 hvalue
from ...
... your query
...
order by case id when '0' then 0 else 1 end desc
```

Comment: Nice one (assuming IDs always start with alphanumeric characters which is mostly true)!

Comment: Hmm.  My code certainly may not work in all circumstances (I was only thinking just about numeric values, TBH).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the context of how the table is being queried, I would do it with following SQL snippet

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID <> 0) 
BEGIN
    SELECT HVALUE FROM MyTable WHERE ID <> 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT HVALUE FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 0
END
```

HTH